# How can I move vertices and keep the faces formed by vertices connected?

Tags: three.js

I want to move vertices from the mask, but the faces created by vertices get cut separated,I want them to stay together , model is BufferGeometry created in blender. Is it possible?What I'm doing wrong?

```
this.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
  this.geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ(i,
  this.geometry.attributes.position.getX(i) + 10,
  this.geometry.attributes.position.getY(i),
  this.geometry.attributes.position.getZ(i));
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXNia.jpg

Comment: I think you're not using indexed geometry, i.e. face is defined by own (i.e. not shared) triple of vertices. Try to convert it to indexed buffer geometry.

Comment: See here for a quick explanation of indexed vs non-indexed geometry: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-9-vbo-indexing/ If you need your vertices connected (AKA indexed, as Alex said), you'll need to export them as such in Blender. It could be that your faces are all separated from its creation in Blender, or maybe you can just turn something on/off in the exporter settings.